# Netrunner and windows 8 dualbooted replace netrunner with ubuntu while keeping windows 8?

Tags: dual-boot, 13.10, windows-8

So i have **netrunner** and **windows 8** (I have a normal bios no new windows 8 bios stuff, used to be a windows 7 machine) and i wanna replace **netrunner** with **ubuntu 13.10**. I have grub installed so no wubi here, do i need to do something special or will the installer just go like hey you have 2 oses wanna replace one with **ubuntu** and keep the other?
If not what do i do? I don't wanna screw up everything because i have important stuff on this computer!

Comment: You have to try. If the installer does not give you the choice you want, you can cancel installation. Backup the data in both, in case you format the wrong partition. Best of luck.

Comment: Well, that dident work. I dunno how to partision either so im screwed...

Comment: Please edit your question and add what choices you get when you try to install Ubuntu. Also, add to the question, a screenshot of gparted or its equivalent from netrunner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete netunner partisions and linux swap
Create new swap and a main partision.
Mark the main partition and continue
Done